# What are good references for spatial dynamics?

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems

Hello I have started working on my PhD a short while ago and wondered if there might be any good introductions to spatial dynamics.

I have a basic understanding of dynamical systems but would like to expand further on it.

Thank you for your recommendations.

Comment: This is a bit broad. What is your advisor suggesting?

Comment: For the beginning he suggested the notes http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/sandsted/documents/spatial-dynamics-notes.pdf to me. I'm sorry I should have been more specific about my intentions: 
I would like to understand the center manifold theorem a bit better and the reduction of pdes to systems of odes in an infinite dimensional space.

Comment: Dan Henry's Geometric Theory of Semilinear Parabolic Equations is a classic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment, the book

M. Haragus, G. Iooss: [Local Bifurcations, Center Manifolds, and Normal Forms in Infinite-Dimensional Dynamical Systems](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780857291110), Springer, 2011

might be of some interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

> Robinson: [Infinite-Dimensional Dynamical Systems](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masdh/book.html): An Introduction
>   to Dissipative Parabolic PDEs and the Theory of Global Attractors